# Server error when sorting generated entity with field name with underscore

Tags: jhipster

I am getting `error.internalServerError` when sorting generated entity in generated table view. It leads to error only in case of fields with database names with underscore. For example **project_owner**.

In my console I am getting this:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/projects?cacheBuster=1489187431846&page=0&size=20&sort=image_logo_url,asc&sort=id 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Is it a bug, or only my local problem?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in wrong parsing. See this URL for more information:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-816

I thought, that when I generate field with name `project_owner`, it will be stored as `project_owner`, but entity name will be camelCase -> **projectOwner**.

So If you have the same issue, check your entity names and refactor them to camelCase syntax.